# How to convert XmlTextWriter to string?

Tags: .net, xslt

I am new to XSLT Transformation world. I'm using XSLT to create an HTML file. How can I get the output as string, so that I can save it to an HTML file?

Performing the transformation using below line:

```
objXtrans.Transform(objDoc, objArgLists, objXmlTxtWriter);
```

How can I convert `objXmlTxtWriter` to get the complete string generated via the `Transform()` method which can be saved as HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the transformation result to be a HTML file then transform to a file (stream), there is no need to first assemble a string in memory to write that complete string to a file.

Unfortunately you have not really told us which API you use, you mention XmlTextWriter in your subject line so I assume it is the .NET framework you use. Since .NET 2.0 the preferred XSLT processor is System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform, if you look at its [Transform method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.transform.aspx) then it has several overloads transforming to a Stream so you could simply use code as follows:

```
XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
proc.Load("sheet.xsl");
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite("result.html"))
{
  proc.Transform(someInput, someArgumentList, stream);
}
```

You have a lot of options for the first argument, it can simply be a string with an input file name or URI, it can be an XmlReader, it can be an object implementing IXPathNavigable (such as an XmlDocument or XPathDocument).

Answer (score 0):

This is really a question about `Stream` and `TextWriter`, not XML.  All of the documentation for .NET's XSLT tools assumes you already know how to do stream- and text-based IO in .NET.  If you don't, you may end up doing a lot of unnecessary work.  (By "you" I mean "I", and by "may" I mean "did.")

Though Martin Honnen correctly observes that in your case you don't actually need to get your output to a string, here's how to do it.  Note that this works with any method that writes to a `TextWriter`, not just `XslCompiledTransform.Transform()`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
{
   MethodThatWritesToATextWriter(sw);
}
string s = sb.ToString();
```

Though you can use a `FileStream` to write to a file in your specific case, `FileStream` is a `Stream`, not a `TextWriter`.  You can only use it with `Transform` because one of the overloads of `Transform` takes a `Stream` as the output parameter.  If you need to use a `TextWriter`, the tool for the job is `StreamWriter`:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename, append))
{
   MethodThatWritesToATextWriter(sw);
}
```